# Camel: Process copy of message / save original message

Tags: apache-camel

Often times, I want to send a message to another route to process it, but I don't want the message to be modified for subsequent steps.  What's the best way to do this?

For example, I want to use a sendMail route to send out an email, which strips out extra headers for safety, but I need to keep the headers for the rest of the main route.

The best approach I've come up with currently is to use multicast with a bogus second route (since the default aggregation strategy is UseLatestAggregationStrategy):

```
<from uri="direct:sendEmail"/>
<multicast>
  <pipeline>
    <removeHeaders pattern="*" excludePattern="(?i)to|cc|bcc|from|subject"/>
    <to ref="mailServer"/>
  </pipeline>

  <transform>
    <description>noop route so that multicast returns original message</description>
    <simple>${body}</simple>
  </transform>
</multicast>
```

... but this is kind of ugly and not really in the spirit of "multicast".

The other option I've found is to use an asynchronous seda endpoint, which returns the original message to the producer and processes a copy, but that introduces asynchronous behavior that may not always be desirable.

Seems like there must be a better way?

Comment: Store the stripped out parts in the header do the sendmail and then reassemble the message?

Comment: How about using the [content enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) with a custom aggregation strategy that discards the enrichment response and returns the original exchange instead?

Comment: @Namphibian: any extra headers will be included in the email message, which is not acceptable here

Comment: @Ralf: Hmm, I think it would, though for enrich you'd have to put the send-mail pipeline in its own route and register a strategy bean

Comment: Yeah I have thought about introducing a stack so you can do a push / pop of the message, then you can just push / do stuff / pop and you are back to what the message was at that given time. Though instead of stack it could be savepoint and have names / ids, save(a) / do stuff / restore(a)

Answer (score 2):

You can check https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Keep-original-message-several-quot-steps-quot-back-td475187.html

Basically you can use `exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage();`  to get the original message